# Pass resolved objects into controllers defined by a string in angular-ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have a set of objects that get resolved using 
    :resolve

I also have a controller that I define by passing it the name as a string but I need to pass in the resolved objects to it.

I know it can be done like this:

```
resolve: { title: 'My Contacts' },
  controller: function($scope, title){
    $scope.title = 'My Contacts';
  }
}
```

but I need to do it like this:

```
resolve: { title: 'My Contacts' },
  controller: 'ResultsController'
}
```

How can I pass in 'title' to my controller in this sense?

Thanks, James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one out (*it should work*):

```
// State configuration...
{
  resolve: {
    title: function () {
      return 'My Contacts';
    }
  },
  controller: 'MyCtrl'  
}

// Controller

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, title) {
  $scope.title = title; 

  console.log($scope.title); // -> 'My Contacts'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the resolve as a function instead.

```
resolve: { 
    title: function() { 
      return 'My Contacts'; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but this is practically the same as above. I was looking to be able to pass title into the controller. Please see my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I thought I tried this but anyway, passing it in as a dependency works:

```
eventaApp.controller('ResultsController', ['$scope', 'resolvedEventsData', function( $scope, resolvedEventsData ) {

    // now have access to resolvedEventsData 

}]);
```